# Android Studio: Error: Program type already present: androidx.core.graphics.PathSegment

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I use Android Studio 3.3 Canary 8.
I created default project and then I tried run the project.
But I had seen following stacktrace:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: androidx.core.graphics.PathSegment","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>   Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>     Program type already present: androidx.core.graphics.PathSegment

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like a bug on recent Android stuff, which occurs even if you create a new project.

I've reported about this recently [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113754614) .

The workaround, which I've found by choosing to migrate to Android-x, is this:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
```

instead of this generated line :

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.3'
```

Answer (score 20):

Replace

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.3'
```

with

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0"// Updated version
```

Answer (score 1):

for this error you have to update this dependency to latest

> `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.3'`